# Image load function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-loading

**GOAL:**
Red borders should became green once image in `.thumbnail` div is loaded

**JSFIDDLE:**
https://jsfiddle.net/3k8xy2cf/

```js
var container;
var img;

$("#products .thumbnail").each(function() {
  container = $(this);
  img = new Image();
  img.src = $(container).find('img').attr('src');
  img.onload = function() {
    $(container).addClass('loaded');
  }
});
```

```css
.product {
  float: left;
  border: 5px solid red;
}
.product.loaded {
  border-color: green;
}
.product img {
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/600x600" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/800x800" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your container is scoped outside the each method.  It's value will be the same for all the load events, and be the last element.  Scope that variable to the each method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: Also side note, the container is already a jQuery object due to you doing `$(this)` so there is no point in re-wrapping it.

Comment: Also swap the onload and the .src lines

Comment: @Taplar Thanks for explanation! Got it https://jsfiddle.net/4rx7wvmz/

Answer (score 2):

Your code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. You don't need the `each()` loop and you certainly don't need to create a new `img` element from the ones which already exist.

Instead you can just use a `load()` event handler on the `img` elements which adds the class to the parent `.thumbnail`, like this:

```js
$('#products .thumbnail img').on('load', function() {
  $(this).closest('.thumbnail').addClass('loaded');
});
```

```css
.thumbnail {
  border: 2px solid #C00;
}

.thumbnail.loaded {
  border-color: #0C0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="products">
  <div class="product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/125x125" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="https://placehold.it/150x150" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How does that work? Surely the load handler is assigned after the page has already loaded, no?